# How To modify Eclipselink JPA 2.0 connection retry behavior 

Tags: jpa, connection, eclipselink, reconnect

How To modify Eclipselink JPA 2.0 connection retry behavior .
Eclipselink automatically tries to reconnect it self to  database whenever  it detects a connection failure this causes swing ui to freeze without any responses until it connects to database .
Are there any solution to modify this behavior 
Ie is it possible to throw exception when connection fails without retrying 
Please help on this issue 
I am facing with huge problem.

I went throe eclipselink source code and google but I could not find any solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using a SessionCustomizer you can disable the connection reconnection.

```
package acme;
import  org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.factories.SessionCustomizer;
import org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.Session;
import org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DatabaseLogin;

public class EmployeeSessionCustomizer implements SessionCustomizer {

    public void customize(Sesssion session) {
        DatabaseLogin login = (DatabaseLogin)session.getDatasourceLogin();
        login.setConnectionHealthValidationOnError(false);
    }
}
```

This customizer can be set through a persistence unit property

```
 <property name="eclipselink.session.customizer" value="acme.EmployeeSessionCustomizer"/>
```

Comment: above also freeze the gui for  about 2 seconds ! any further is improvements can be done

Comment: When the gui freezes take a stack dump.  Is it possible the gui is frozen because it is operating against the Persistence Unit and the Persistence Unit is attempting to connect to database?  If that is the case then you will need to resolve the connection delay or have one thread used for the gui and another for the Persistence work.  Or at least have a separate thread that monitors the database connection and disallows persistence calls until the database is connected.

Comment: It seems sometime between the accepted answer and EclipseLink 2.7 the method was renamed and is now called `setConnectionHealthValidatedOnError`.