# Eclipselink retry query after exception

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, eclipselink

I'm using JPA/Eclipselink to connect to a PostgreSQL instance which is in a HA mode. When a failover of the PostgreSQL is triggered the current master instance will turn on a read only mode. Sometimes, I hit the exact moment of the failover and receive an `PSQLException: Fatal terminating connection due to administrator command` while inserting some data. This occurs because I'm also using a connection pool. When retrying the same statement it works again as the connection is reconnected. Are there any best practices to avoid such a situation? Of course, I can wrap the JPA `EntityManager` and build some kind of retry mechanism. I also found an exception handler [1] where the documentation explizitly mentions a retry of the query:

> Use the handleException method of the class, which takes a
>   java.lang.RuntimeException, to:
>
> Re-throw the exception
>
> Throw a different exception
>
> Retry the query or database operation.

I've not found a single example regading an `ExceptionHandler` with a "Retry the query or database operation".

Regards

[1] https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/jpa/extensions/p_exception_handler.htm#CCHCJCDJ

Comment: I generally look for code examples in the EclipseLink test classes on GitHub: https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/eclipselink. What you may want more though is to reuse the existing retry mechanics EclipseLink is already using (somewhat described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289075/how-to-modify-eclipselink-jpa-2-0-connection-retry-behavior) and just have your error included as as one your DB platform class marks as connection based (see wasFailureCommunicationBased which you may need to override on a custom platform class)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the tests. I've found one which gave me at least an idea of the handling [1]. I'm using `transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL"` so every transaction is controlled by me. A typical persist looks like `EntityTransaction t = em.getTransaction();   t.begin();  em.persist(entity);  t.commit();`. I'm not sure if I'm able to retry a transaction within the `ExceptionHandler`

[1] https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/eclipselink/blob/14e754b5159b1a28441452fa9dda45e74fb294bb/foundation/eclipselink.core.test/src/it/java/org/eclipse/persistence/testing/tests/feature/Handler.java

Comment: It also seems like the existing retry mechanims of eclipselink is also not cabable of retrying a transaction when an exception occurs. At least I don't find anything regarding this.

Comment: It is only capable of retrying the last statement/query operation, not the full transaction - I wouldn't trust it to run the full transaction for me regardless, as anything long running would be extraordinarily long running at the worst of times, and open to failures as things change out from under it. IMO Better to let the upper layers get the exception and retry the operations as needed